# Can't resolve all parameters' JwtInterceptor

Tags: angular

When i start building my application which the main purpose was to implement login service, whenever, when it starts, it shows blank page and i get this error from console which is:

```
compiler.js:2193 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for JwtInterceptor: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2193)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:17643)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:17539)
```

Spent much time on googling, don’t have an idea what to do…

Here is how I provide the Interceptor in AppModule:

```
 providers: [CookieService,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Here is the Interceptor itself:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


    constructor(private userService: UserService,
    ) {

    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        const currentUser = this.userService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `${currentUser.type} ${currentUser.token}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Here is th UserService :

```
Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<JwtResponse>;
    public currentUser: Observable<JwtResponse>;
    public nameTerms = new Subject<string>();
    public name$ = this.nameTerms.asObservable();
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private cookieService: CookieService) {
        const memo = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<JwtResponse>(JSON.parse(memo));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
        cookieService.set('currentUser', memo);
    }

    get currentUserValue() {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }


    login(loginForm): Observable<JwtResponse> {
        const url = `${apiUrl}/login`;
        return this.http.post<JwtResponse>(url, loginForm).pipe(
            tap(user => {
                if (user && user.token) {
                    this.cookieService.set('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    if (loginForm.remembered) {
                        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    }
                    console.log((user.name));
                    this.nameTerms.next(user.name);
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                    return user;
                }
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError('Login Failed', null))
        );
    }

    logout() {
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.cookieService.delete('currentUser');
    }


    private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

            console.log(error); // log to console instead

            // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
            return of(result as T);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular services are also providers and subjected to be declared as that.
That's why when Angular injection tries to inject `JwtInterceptor` with `UserService` it can not do it because it doesn't identify it.

Please add `UserService` after `CookieService` as well.

Comment: I chage it like this  providers: [CookieService,UserService, ..,..]¨and i get another one Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (?, ?).

Comment: That's probably an issue that your UserService is not injectable, usually meaning you passed to it parameters that are not marked as injectable. Try editing your question and add to the bottom of the post the userservice constructors.

Comment: I edit it, u can check, the injectable is present there.

Comment: Have you added the following `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` to app module file, and also added `HttpClientModule` into `imports` at app module ?

Comment: @HamzaKhadhri, Also `Injectable` should be `@Injectable`